# Combining Trees and Nodes, value unaccessible

Tags: c, binary-tree

i'm experimenting with trees and nodes and I having trouble.
I have

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    int cuenta;
    int fondo;
    struct nodo *sig;
}pNodo;
typedef pNodo *tLista;

typedef struct tree
{
    int RUT;
    struct tree *izq;
    struct tree *der;
    struct nodo *tLista;
}tTree;
typedef tTree *tABB;
typedef tTree *tNodo;

void crearArbol(tABB arbol)
{
    tABB nuevoA;
    nuevoA=(tABB)malloc(sizeof(tTree));
    arbol=nuevoA;
    arbol->izq=NULL;
    arbol->der=NULL;
}

int AgregarCuenta(tABB *arbol,int rut,int id_cuenta,int saldo)
{
    tABB AUX;
    AUX=*arbol;
    tLista nuevaC;
    int i=1;
    if(AUX==NULL)
    {
        crearArbol(AUX);
        if(id_cuenta==1)
        {
            (AUX->tLista)->fondo=saldo;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(rut==AUX->RUT)
        {
            while(AUX->tLista!=NULL)
            {
                if(AUX->tLista->cuenta==id_cuenta)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    AUX->tLista=AUX->tLista->sig;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            nuevaC=(tLista)malloc(sizeof(pNodo));
            nuevaC->sig=NULL;
            nuevaC->cuenta=i;
            nuevaC->fondo=saldo;
            AUX->tLista=nuevaC;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(rut<AUX->RUT)
            {
                AUX=AUX->izq;
                AgregarCuenta(&AUX,rut,id_cuenta,saldo);
            }
            else
            {
                AUX=AUX->der;
                AgregarCuenta(&AUX,rut,id_cuenta,saldo);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    tABB arbolillo;
    crearArbol(arbolillo);
    AgregarCuenta(&arbolillo, 18020200, 1, 9999);

    return 0;
}
```

It dies on "(AUX->tLista)->fondo=saldo;" at the AgregarCuenta function. with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it would certainly help if the code used English identifiers

Comment: @sehe: learn to read the code in the abstract...

Comment: @Jonathan: I didn't say it can't be done :) I guess I was saying: it is preventing me from reading your code right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `crearArbol` requires a pointer to a pointer as input:

```
void crearArbol(tABB *arbol)
{
    tABB nuevoA = (tABB)malloc(sizeof(tTree));
    if (nuevoA == 0)
        ...handle out of memory error...
    *arbol = nuevoA;
    (*arbol)->izq = NULL;
    (*arbol)->der = NULL;
}
```

And the call:

```
crearArbol(&AUX);
```

Otherwise, you don't 'return' the value to the calling code.

---

Additionally, just after that you have:

```
    if(id_cuenta==1)
    {
        (AUX->tLista)->fondo=saldo;
        return 0;
    }
```

But if you've just called `crearArbol()` there is no initialization of the `tLista` member, so it points at garbage.  You need to allocate the space for it to point to, and set the `tLista` member to point to it; then you can set the `fondo` member of that allocated space.  Make sure you initialize every member of every structure...

---

*Update 1*: fixed notation in `crearArbol()` - the extra parentheses are needed.  You also have to worry about the call to `crearArbol()` in `main()`, which I missed before.  You are missing a `return` from `AgregarCuenta()`, or the return type should be `void` and the other `return` statements in the function would lose the value.  Since you don't check the returned value, it is not clear which is better.

---

*Update 2*: this code compiles and runs.  It leaks memory, of course.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    int cuenta;
    int fondo;
    struct nodo *sig;
}pNodo;
typedef pNodo *tLista;

typedef struct tree
{
    int RUT;
    struct tree *izq;
    struct tree *der;
    struct nodo *tLista;
}tTree;
typedef tTree *tABB;
typedef tTree *tNodo;

static void crearArbol(tABB *arbol)
{
    tABB nuevoA = (tABB)malloc(sizeof(tTree));
    *arbol=nuevoA;
    (*arbol)->izq = NULL;
    (*arbol)->der = NULL;
    (*arbol)->tLista = malloc(sizeof(pNodo));
    (*arbol)->tLista->cuenta = -1;
    (*arbol)->tLista->fondo = -1;
    (*arbol)->tLista->sig = NULL;
}

static int AgregarCuenta(tABB *arbol, int rut, int id_cuenta, int saldo)
{
    tABB AUX;
    AUX=*arbol;
    tLista nuevaC;
    int i=1;
    if(AUX==NULL)
    {
        crearArbol(&AUX);
        if(id_cuenta==1)
        {
            (AUX->tLista)->fondo=saldo;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(rut==AUX->RUT)
        {
            while(AUX->tLista!=NULL)
            {
                if(AUX->tLista->cuenta==id_cuenta)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    AUX->tLista=AUX->tLista->sig;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            nuevaC=(tLista)malloc(sizeof(pNodo));
            nuevaC->sig=NULL;
            nuevaC->cuenta=i;
            nuevaC->fondo=saldo;
            AUX->tLista=nuevaC;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(rut<AUX->RUT)
            {
                AUX=AUX->izq;
                return AgregarCuenta(&AUX,rut,id_cuenta,saldo);
            }
            else
            {
                AUX=AUX->der;
                return AgregarCuenta(&AUX,rut,id_cuenta,saldo);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    tABB arbolillo;
    crearArbol(&arbolillo);
    AgregarCuenta(&arbolillo, 18020200, 1, 9999);

    return 0;
}
```

When run with `valgrind`, I get:

```
==25013== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25013== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25013== Using Valgrind-3.6.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25013== Command: tree
==25013== 
==25013== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25013==    at 0x100000DC0: AgregarCuenta (tree.c:54)
==25013==    by 0x100000EC5: main (tree.c:95)
==25013== 
==25013== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25013==    at 0x100000E52: AgregarCuenta (tree.c:77)
==25013==    by 0x100000EC5: main (tree.c:95)
==25013== 
==25013== 
==25013== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25013==     in use at exit: 184 bytes in 5 blocks
==25013==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 0 frees, 184 bytes allocated
==25013== 
==25013== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25013==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==25013==    indirectly lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==25013==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25013==    still reachable: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
==25013==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25013== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==25013== 
==25013== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25013== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==25013== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: @Diego: you would have to show the updated memory allocation code for anyone to be able to comment on why you still have problems.  Keep the original code in the question, but also show what changed.